# Streaming Video In Scala InfoChannel Designer 5

Tags: video-streaming, scala-designer

I am having the hardest time finding urls to use in Scala Designer 5 showing video streams. I am new at this program, but there is an option to run a video as a background. I have found a couple of samples to link to, but nothing great thus far. Anyone out there using this program and wanting to do the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you have to find url streams out there on the good old internet, but I could never find anything relevant. I'm sure they are out there, but to keep the project going I just added videos I downloaded from various resources as backgrounds in the script. If I ever actually figure out my real intentions, I'll repost :)

Answer (score 1):

Content like streaming video is bandwidth intensive. As such, I guess folks don't like to make their streams public. That takes away the easy solution but it does make us focus on supplying local content within our product. There is a way. Many IP-based webcams have a slew of options for sending image stills, Motion JPEG and streaming video back to the user. This could be handled on your local network... assuming you have some place interesting to point the camera toward. Alternately, you can find a place away from your LAN and configure the unit to send a secure private stream to the IP destination of your choosing. On the same theme, you could get a TV capture card or perhaps a Slingbox to pull content from traditional video media and serve up a stream that way.